# How can I turn a 2nd order PDE into a 1st order PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am having some difficulty with a beam equation and I need to convert the equation below into a 1st order PDE with respect to time in order to compare with my code calculations.

In case the picture does not load, the equation is (rearranged to equal $\frac{d^2w}{dt^2}$ ):

$$\frac{d^2 w}{dt^2}= -\left(\frac{EI}{pA}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{d^4w}{dx^4}\right)$$

The original equation:
[image: Beam vibration equation]

I want to turn the 2nd degree PDE in terms of $t$ into a 1st degree PDE in terms of t. I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that:
$$w(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$
then you will see your equation reduces to:
$$X(x)T''(t)=-CX''''(x)T(t)$$
multiplying both sides by $T'$
$$X(x)T''T'=-CX''''TT'$$
and now integrating wrt $t$. Notice that:
$$\left[\frac12(T')^2\right]'=T''T'$$
$$\left[\frac12T^2\right]'=TT'$$
and so we get:
$$X(x)\times\frac12(T')^2=-CX''''\times\frac12T^2$$
$$X(T')^2=-CX''''T^2$$
now you could rearrange:
$$T'=j\sqrt{\frac{CX''''T^2}{X}}$$
However this is quite complicated

---

A common way used is to convert from 1 second order equation to 2 first order coupled equations, say:
$$z_1(t)=T(t),\,z_2(t)=T'(t)$$
now it is clear that:
$$z_1'(t)=T'(t)=z_2,\,z_2'(t)=T''(t)=-\frac{CX''''(x)T(t)}{X(x)}=-\frac{CX''''(x)z_1}{X(x)}$$
now letting:
$$\mathbf{z}=\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{pmatrix}$$
you obtain:
$$\mathbf{z}'=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-\frac{CX''''(x)}{X(x)} & 0\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{M}}\mathbf{z}$$
and so you now have the first order equation:
$$\mathbf{z}'=\mathbf{Mz}$$